# Lucene date range with multiple occurrences

Tags: java, lucene, range-query

I'm writing an application for doctors planning. A doctor is a Java object having an ID, a name and a collection of plannings.
A planning is described by {start_date, end_date, planning_type}.
Dates are formatted as YYYY-MM-DD.
Now, consider doctor A having two planning ranges:
(Click on "run code snippet" code to see the planning as a HTML table)

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><th>start_date</th><th>end_date</th><th>type</th></tr>
<tr><td>2016-01-01</td><td>2015-01-05</td><td>night</td></tr>
<tr><td>2016-01-11</td><td>2015-01-15</td><td>night</td></tr>
</table>
```

If we try  to check if this doctor is working in 2016-01-07 for example, the query should look like :

```
+planning.start_date:[0 TO "2016-01-07"] +planning.end_date:["2016-01-07" TO A]
```

This query will return doctor A in the result set, although this is not true. Actually doctor A won't be at work, but, because of the way Lucene stores collections, this query matches doctor A.

Is there a way (including adding extra fields, ....) to get this working as expected?

Comment: One ugly way to deal with this, is to add another field (enumDate) and enumerate all the days in all the intervals. Then the query would be:
(+planning.enumDate:"2016-01-07")
Any other suggestion is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

How about making a Lucene document for every planning instead of every doctor ?

Comment: I can't see how this can solve the problem. Could you please develop your suggestion?

Comment: just in your example there will be two documents stored in lucene:
    

    `doctor:X from : 2016-01-01 to : 2015-01-05 type: night`
    `doctor:X from : 2016-01-11 to : 2015-01-15 type: night`

so the query 
    `planning.start_date:[0 TO "2016-01-07"] +planning.end_date:["2016-01-07" TO A]`
will not match any of the documents